# How to get keys in Object array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object array created and it's like this:

```
for(var i =0; i < this.test.length; i ++){
    var header = this.test[i].hdr;
    var insertData = [];

    switch(header){
        case 'date':
            insertData =  {date: "date"};
            break;
        case 'name':
            insertData =  {name: "name"};
            break;
        case 'age':
            insertData =  {age: "age"};
            break;
        case 'add':
            insertData =  {add: "add"};
            break;
    }
    this.hdrtxt.push(insertData);
}
```

Now, when I try to get the keys of the object, I used this:

```
Object.keys(this.hdrtxt);
```

The result  is:

```
(4) ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

But the output I want is this:

```
(4) ["date", "name", "age", "add"]
```

I'm sorry I'm just new to this. How can I attain my goal?

Comment: How are you calling `Object.keys(this.hdr)`? `.hdr` looks like a property of each object in the `this.test` array.

Comment: @achacttn Opppss updated. Variable name typo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread the `data` into one object to get all the keys:

```js
const data = [{ date: "date" }, { name: "name" }, { age: "age" }, { add: "add" }]

const result = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data))

console.log(result)
```

The main reason for this is due to the fact that you are dealing with an array and `Object.keys` expects an object to work.

Comment: Just a question, what does `...` mean? Thanks.

Comment: It is ES6 spread operator, which basically gets all the objects and lists them as parameters to the Object.assign function

Answer (score 0):

First off that could be done much easier in a reduce

```js
const test = [{hdr: "date"}, {hdr: "name"}, {hdr: "age"}, {hdr: "add"}];

const results = test.reduce((result, item) => [...result, { [item.hdr]: item.hdr }], []);

// This logs, ["0", "1", "2", "3"] because it is an array and the keys are integers.
console.log(Object.keys(results));

// If you want the object keys for each item in the array try mapping each item in the array to it's first key in the keys for that item
console.log(results.map(item => Object.keys(item)[0]));
```

Comment: I can now understand better. But the situation is not like that.  It's like this : `const results = [{date : "date"}, {name: "name"}, {age: "age"}, {add: "add"}]`. Thanks :)